# Is investing getting harder?

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing, united-kingdom, investment-strategies

I've often heard that to make irregular rates of return in the markets, one has to accomplish two things:

1) Bet against the consensus.

2) Be right.

This makes sense - roughly speaking. Given that we live in an ever more intelligent world/society. Are models/assumptions of human behaviour as reactionary, 'short-term driven', financially illiterate sheep becoming less an less relevant as more people become educated, connected and self-aware?

And as a result is investing getting harder for individuals as the generations become more competitive?

(Note: I realise that this is difficult to answer quantitatively. So save that, I don't mind qualitative subjective answers).

Comment: You don't need #1 if you have #2 from your list.

Comment: When was investing easy? :->)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are focusing on market-beating ("irregular") returns. The biggest problem most investors have had is that they lag the market, not even achieving the "regular" (and quite good) long-term returns that it offers. Matching the market has become *easier* with low-cost index funds and ETFs. Doing so should be viewed as winning, not losing.

Beating the market through trading has probably become more difficult due to the increasing sophistication and resources of large short-term traders. However, there are still presumably patterns with some predictability due to the remaining influence of human behavior and psychology.

In fact, there must always be some value to research and trading by someone, or the assumptions underlying indexing would [break down](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/john-bogle-has-a-warning-for-index-fund-investors-2017-06-01). If enough people give up on active investing in favor of passive investing, individual securities can become mispriced and the benefits of active investing can increase. Likely there is a rational equilibrium with active investing by the most capable institutions and passive investing by everyone else.

Comment: Many state that trading is more difficult because you're going up against larger players with  increased  sophistication and resources.  It's you versus them.  They have many advantages: HFT and colocation, priority access to arbitrage, super computers, algorithms, etc.  Just my opinion but I don't think that the big players have a trading advantage when it comes to one off news events - for example,   earnings announcements.  The stock goes in play and then  you and your risk management determines success not the aforementioned size  of others.